# Display File contents on the Web Browser UI

Tags: ruby, html, node.js, user-interface, web

I am looking to deploy a Web Interface to display file that has log contents. I am collecting the log details and storing them on my WebServer. I have an Apache interface that lets user download/view the file from the browser.

However, the challenge here is that they don't look pretty. I want to show them in a UI that can highlight/color contents. I tried to simply pull the contents of the file and display in a Text Area which works but that would mean doing a lot of manual work to make it fancy. Wondering if something already exist that i could re-use ?

As a future enhancement I was also hoping that the UI would find for patterns in the file and highlight them in the UI. For example, If the file contains connection refused messages just highlight them in red etc..

I am not sure if I should build something from scratch or something already exist that i can re-use ?

Comment: When generating the HTML, you could put the content you want to highlight inside divs (or other tag) of a specific class. You could customize the style of this class with CSS, adding any effects you want. You'll still need to implement something to identify the chunks of data to be highlighted, but that is completely dependent on  how the log file is organized. For example, if each row represents a single event, whose type is identified by a specific keyword, you could use this keyword to decide whether or not to place each row into a highlighted div.

Comment: Is this a rails app or node?

Comment: None just a concept in my head... I am fine implementing it in either of those

Answer (score 0):

I would use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and set to [read-only](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly) or completely hide the editor controls.